# Using the Facebook API, is there a way to restrict registration to a certain attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

Say I only want those who mark their country as Indonesia to sign up for my site. Is this possible to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer Yes. But to do that your potential new user would have to try to signup to your site first so you can use the Facebook API and inspect their hometown or current location, then if they are not from Indonesia you can block their access.